# Java class organization

Tags: java, access-modifiers

Reading this java text and the authors advise thinking about the package org leaving only the classes really required to be open to the rest of the world as public.

I think I get the point that bit exposing what is not needed allows changing stuff later without breaking client code - but, I can't think of an example -

If a package let's say has a couple of entities or classes each providing a set of functionality - would the public facing class then have to orchestrate all the communication with the external world?

Any examples or guidance would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Yes. Because only the `public` class can be seen by the outside world.

Comment: Ok - so if I wanted to organize lets say the following classes - 


Class-1: "Platform" (MySQL/SQL Server/Oracle)
 - list platforms

Class-2: "DataStore"
 - Class-3: "Oracle"
   - create
   - updateByHostService
   - listAll
 -Class-4: "Salesforce"
   - create
   - updateByURL
   - listAll

So if I wrap all this into a package, what is a recommended design for the public API of this package? and why?

(I can only think of providing a way to share the UNION of all the methods of individual classes - pretty sure thats not cool)

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Answer (score 3):

Basically it's about not making commitments to client code unless you need to. When you make a method public, then in some contexts at least you're committing to not changing it without coordinating with client code.

Suppose you make a method public and somebody uses it. Then later you realize you need to change the method. Now you have two choices:

1. Coordinate with that client to make the change.
2. Break the client.

Obviously you want to avoid #2 if possible.

For small systems, #1 may not be a big deal. But as you have more client code depending on your code, #1 can become really problematic. Someone may not be ready to absorb your change for whatever reason (schedule, business reason, technical reason, whatever).

A good way to avoid this dilemma is to avoid making commitments unless there's some reason to. This is really a smart thing to do in life generally, even outside of programming. But it applies to programming too: with respect to visibility, that means preferring limited visibility over public visibility.

**An example.** Say I'm writing an ecommerce order management library, and I write a method

```
public double computeTax(double price) { ... }
```

even though all the library's tax calculations happen internally to the library. I just make the method public because I think it would be a shame not to share my tax calculator with the world.

A bunch of people agree that this method is great, and build apps that use it.

Then somebody points out that it's totally wrong to use doubles to represent dollar amounts (floating point representations are only approximations, which is no good for money). I decide that I want to completely get rid of the old method (don't want anybody using something fundamentally wrong), and replace it with

```
public Currency computeTax(Currency price) { ... }
```

But now I'm going to break a bunch of client code that uses the original method.

It would have been better if I had just kept my crummy tax calculator to myself, since it wasn't part of what the library was really offering anyway. Now I'm stuck with the dilemma.

Comment: Thanks willie - that makes sense - although doesn't that make for a ' loaded' public 'interface' class  ?

Comment: What I mean by that is - let's say there is a package purely with 2 classes - each providing 3 methods each - would this public facing class then provide 6 methods in the worst case ? Or close? In case some methods of the one class consume some of the other?

Comment: I might need to see your example in code. You can just add it to the question.

Comment: Ok - I dont have code yet - I am thinking prior to building this out - I have 2 entities -  say - 

1) Platform (like SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, SFTP etc .. )
2) DataStore - a specific instance of a Platform - say x.y.com:1521/adhoc is a datastore on the "Oracle" platform 

Each of them - Platform and DataStore - would provide methods - like create, edit, and remove

In this case - 

1) would it make sense to include both these in the same package
2) If so, per the principle being discussed, should DataStore alone be made public, and Platform package private?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the principle I follow mostly. Make visibility of Class or methods or even parameter to lowest possible visibility.  Facade pattern is a good practice to expose collective functionality of classes. Other good practice is to use object as parameter type for public API then convert it internally to desired type, this way you can avoid potential code break.